# Generate interactive images on Facebook posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm looking into expanding our product line by allowing dynamic images as a graph api post via facebook.  I was looking at making dynamic images (something like: http://mashable.com/2013/04/23/thinglink-facebook/#sceLSDRqmkqQ).  Is there a way to make a dynamic image on the facebook wall?
I don't know if that makes any sense, but I was just wondering how ThingLink creates those kinds of interactive images when it looks like Graph just allows static images.

Thanks!

Comment: Flash is allowed. So you can use that

Comment: Oh nice!  I'm totally new to flash...is there a good resource you could point me to to learn how to create dynamic flash objects using dynamic images?